# Having a composition relationship in ASP .NET?

Tags: list, gridview, datagridview

I have a Car composed by a Driver. I have problems showing either informations on the gridview. It's only shows Car's info. on the gridview, and I wanna display like: Car: Lancia Driver: Sandro, something like that.

Here's the code:

Car:

[Serializable]
    public class Car
    {
        public String Brand { get; set; }
        public String Model { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public Driver Driver { get; set; }

```
    public Car(String Brand, String Model, int Year, Driver Driver)
    {
        Brand = Brand;
        Model = Model;
        Year = Year;
        Driver = Driver;
    }


    public Car()
    {
        Init();
    }

    public void Init()
    {
        Brand = string.Empty;
        Model = string.Empty;
        Year = 0;
        Driver = new Driver();
    }
```

Driver:

[Serializable]
    public class Driver
    {
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public String Nationality { get; set; }

```
    public Driver(String Name, int Age, String Nationality)
    {
        Name = Name;
        Age = Age;
        Nationality = Nationality;

    }

    public Driver()
    {
        Init();

    }

    public void Init()
    {
        Name = string.Empty;
        Age = 0;
        Nationality = string.Empty;

    }

}
```

aspx.cs:

public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

```
    //private ArrayList garageList;
    private List<Car> garageList; 
    private static int counterPost = 0;
    private static int counterLoad = 0;

    public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        TextBox masterTextLoad = (TextBox) Master.FindControl("txtLoad");

        masterTextLoad.Text = Convert.ToString(counterLoad++);


        if (IsPostBack)
        {

            TextBox masterTextPost = (TextBox) Master.FindControl("txtPost");

            masterTextPost.Text = Convert.ToString(counterPost++);


            garageList = (List<Car>)ViewState["Cars"];

            //garageList = (ArrayList) ViewState["Cars"];

            if (garageList == null)
            {
                //garageList = new ArrayList();
                garageList = new List<Car>();
            }
        }

    }

    protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //Driver
        Driver driver = new Driver();

        TextBox driverName = (TextBox) Master.FindControl("txtName");
        driver.Name = driverName.Text;

        TextBox driverAge = (TextBox) Master.FindControl("txtAge");
        driver.Age = Convert.ToInt32(driverAge.Text);

        TextBox driverNationality = (TextBox)Master.FindControl("txtNationality");
        driver.Nationality = driverNationality.Text;



        //Car
        Car car = new Car();


        car.Brand = txtBrand.Text;
        car.Model = txtModel.Text;
        car.Year = Int32.Parse(txtYear.Text);



        garageList.Add(car);

        //ViewState["Cars"] = garageList;

        ViewState["garageList"] = garageList;

        cleanControls();

    }

    private void cleanControls()
    {

        //Cleaning driver controls
        TextBox masterTextPost = (TextBox)Master.FindControl("txtPost");
        masterTextPost.Text = string.Empty;

        TextBox driverName = (TextBox)Master.FindControl("txtName");
        driverName.Text = string.Empty;

        TextBox driverAge = (TextBox)Master.FindControl("txtAge");
        driverAge.Text= string.Empty;

        TextBox driverNationality = (TextBox)Master.FindControl("txtNationality");
        driverNationality.Text = string.Empty;

        //Cleaning Car controls
        txtBrand.Text = String.Empty;
        txtModel.Text = String.Empty;
        txtYear.Text = String.Empty;

    }

    protected void btnShow_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        grvShow.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        grvShow.DataSource = garageList;
        grvShow.DataBind();
        //grvShow.Visible = true;


    }
}
```

Comment: Please narrow your problem down to the specific issue.  Posting your entire code here is not helpful, and will be difficult for somebody to try and help you.

Comment: I can't narrow it, but, it's on btnAdd on aspx.cs.